# Adding alias A record and A records on different domain and host

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I have a general question. If my domain and host provider are different, as far as I got, the A and CNAME records only should be written in the domain provider. Then how is about alias? Could I have alias A record in the host?

My problem is that my domain provider does not support alias, but the host has an alias that I need to set in DNS setting in order to use SSL certificate and load balancer (AWS EC2).

In Route 53 of AWS you could assign alias A record and I did it, but still my site does not load and I wonder if is there a conflict between my domain DNS A record (which is only the IP and www.ip address) and Route 53.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit unsure what you mean, but let me attempt an answer:

Your server needs a certificate for the name your clients will try to reach. So for example, if you want your clients to access your service by typing https://example.com in their web browser, then your service needs to present a certificate for `example.com` no matter the actual FQDNs of your server(s). Then you point an A record at the IP address of your server(s) or a CNAME at their actual FQDN.

If your current DNS provider can't provide the services your company needs you should probably look at switching providers. It's entirely possible to have different companies providing your server hosting, your domain registration, and your DNS if required, if you're willing to accept the management overhead.

Comment: I think I had some misunderstanding. I used the AWS name servers inside my domain provider so now I could add everything inside Route 53 directly